# Directory permission in AIX is changing to nobody

Tags: aix

I am using an AIX system. The directory I am using is on GPFS(Type mmfs in mount command) [Not NFS]. What I am seeing is time to time the ownership is changing to nobody. I was wondering if someone can help me understand what activity can change the directory ownership to nobody. I am not expecting the root user to run chown specifically. What else could trigger this change of ownership.
Following is some of the directory and file system listing -

```
$ ls -ld /x/y/z
drwxr-xr-x  165 nobody   app_dev       65536 Jan 31 19:41 /x/y/z
$


$ df -g /x/y/z
Filesystem    GB blocks      Free %Used    Iused %Iused Mounted on
/dev/gpfsfl   654865.87  46975.80   93% 35495352    97% /x/y
$


$ ls -ld /x/y
drwxrwxr-x  172 app      app_dev       65536 Jan 14 15:32 /x/y
$
```

Comment: Try unix.stackexchange.com or superuser.com.

Comment: use the `flag` link at the bottom of your question and ask the moderator to move to unix.stackexchange.com. good luck.